# PS4, Get-WMIObject returns PID=0 for an in-house developed service

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

Thanks in advance.

Here is a Powershell4 script that we're running:

```
$process = Get-WMiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name ='HotKeyService'" 
write-host Process Name = $process.name
write-host Process ID = $process.processid

$oopid = $process.processid
stop-process -id $oopid -force
wait-process -id $oopid -timeout 60 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
-------------------------------
working directory: C:\Program Files\HK\HK.HotKeyService
```

With this I get:

```
Process Name = HotKeyService
Process ID = 0
```

Error#1

> stop-process : Cannot stop process "Idle (0)" because of the following
>       error:  Access is denied
>       At C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp206027652026805712.ps1:6 char:1
>       + stop-process -id $oopid -force
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.Diagnostics.Process (Idle):P 
>          rocess) [Stop-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopProcess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Command 
>          s.StopProcessCommand

Error#2

> wait-process : This command stopped operation because it cannot wait
>   on 
>       'System Idle' process. Specify another process and Run your command again.
>       At C:\Windows\TEMP\tmp206027652026805712.ps1:7 char:1
>       + wait-process -id $oopid -timeout 60 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (System.Diagnostics.Process
>       (Idl 
>          e):Process) [Wait-Process], ProcessCommandException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
>       WaitOnIdleProcess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands. 
>          WaitProcessCommand

```
===============================
command exit code: 0
```

The code above is part of a larger process that gets run on many services on Windows 2012 servers and Win 7 workstations.  Sometimes though it fails and I don't know why.  In this case, the correct service name is retrieved which can be seen in the command ouptut but the PID is 0, which can't possibly be correct as that's the system idle process's PID.

The parent software calling this PS script later shows that files in the HotKey install folder cannot be updated because, "(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)", which makes sense because the HotKeyService service didn't stop correctly.

I ran the parent software again and it worked correctly on the same service.

My question is how could Get-WMIObject return the correct service name but then on the next step show a PID of zero?  I can't figure this one out.

Thanks for the assistance.
KJ

Comment: I would suggest you add a step to check the PID and if it is 0, either try again a number of times or gracefully produce an error. It might be very difficult / impossible to track down why it fails at times so probably simpler to retry

Answer (score 2):

When you see a `Win32_Service` instance with a `ProcessId` value of `0`, it simply means that the service isn't running.

You'll find that:

```
(Get-WMiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name ='HotKeyService'").State
```

is `Stopped`